# How to get my ERC20 token listed on Metamask

Tags: erc-20, metamask

I would like to add my ERC20 token to Metamask, so that when users type its name into the search bar, it shows up along with its logo. Currently users can add their tokens manually. But, I'm wondering how can I add my token to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the Metamask's submission process and comply with their criteria as described in their official [GitHub repository](https://github.com/MetaMask/contract-metadata). It actually looks relatively hard to be listed, as you need to meet requirements such as activity or neutral/OK reputation on Etherscan besides all the technical requirements.

However, there is an interesting workaround that allows your users to add the token by just clicking a button from your website. It is provided by Metamask as well and you can try a live demo or [get the code](https://github.com/MetaMask/Add-Token) developed in React.js. You just need to click a button and confirm the action:

**Step 1**: From your website, click on 'Watch in Wallet'

[image]

**Step 2**: Confirm the action in Metamask

[image]

**Step 3**: And there you go! (no need to add it manually by typing the contract address)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's an example of how to do this on MetaMask's [website](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/registering-your-token.html#code-free-example) -

```js
const tokenAddress = '0xd00981105e61274c8a5cd5a88fe7e037d935b513';
const tokenSymbol = 'TUT';
const tokenDecimals = 18;
const tokenImage = 'http://placekitten.com/200/300';

try {
  // wasAdded is a boolean. Like any RPC method, an error may be thrown.
  const wasAdded = await ethereum.request({
    method: 'wallet_watchAsset',
    params: {
      type: 'ERC20', // Initially only supports ERC20, but eventually more!
      options: {
        address: tokenAddress, // The address that the token is at.
        symbol: tokenSymbol, // A ticker symbol or shorthand, up to 5 chars.
        decimals: tokenDecimals, // The number of decimals in the token
        image: tokenImage, // A string url of the token logo
      },
    },
  });

  if (wasAdded) {
    console.log('Thanks for your interest!');
  } else {
    console.log('Your loss!');
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

They also have a Token Add Widget [tool](https://vittominacori.github.io/watch-token/create/) in case you just want to embed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing Metamask is using some sort of Popular Tokens lists from Coinmarketcap or Coingecko APIs.
If you want to appear there you probably need to be a high market cap token.

Edit: Actually they have their own list and you need to "apply" there : https://github.com/MetaMask/contract-metadata.

Good luck !

Comment: A link to contract-metada is in included in the old answer in their README they say the repository is frozen so they don't accept new submissions hence the need for an updated answer.

Comment: well you're right, the README says submissions are closed but  if you check the PRs , they are still adding coins ... so it's not completely a dead end I guess..